# Grouping by ShopName Count Different type of Customer(membership)

Tags: sql-server, linq

We have a 2 tables

**Table 1**
Shop where we have shop details

```
ShopNo, ShopName
```

**Table 2**
Customer where we have all customer details

```
CustomerId, CustomerName, MembershipType, ShopId
```

what we are trying to query is

```
ShopName   SilverMember GoldMember LifeMember

ABC        45           110        1

XYZ        90           0          10

DEF        10           10         7
```

Is there a way to make it possible

if in Linq well and good else only sql query will do thanks in advance

Regards
Moksha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
select s.ShopName,
       count(c1.CustomerId) as 'SilverMember',
       count(c2.CustomerId) as 'GoldMember',
       count(c3.CustomerId) as 'LifeMember'
from Shop s
left outer join Customer c1 on c1.ShopId = s.ShopNo and c1.MembershipType = 'SilverMember'
left outer join Customer c2 on c2.ShopId = s.ShopNo and c2.MembershipType = 'GoldMember'
left outer join Customer c3 on c3.ShopId = s.ShopNo and c3.MembershipType = 'LifeMember'
group by s.ShopName
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `MembershipType` contains the actual VARCHAR values `SilverMember`, `GoldMember`, and `LifeMember`, this should work in T-SQL:

```
SELECT
    [ShopName], COUNT([SilverMember]) AS [SilverMember], COUNT([GoldMember]) AS [GoldMember], COUNT([LifeMember]) AS [LifeMember]
FROM
    [Table1]
    INNER JOIN [Table2]
        ON [Table1].[ShopNo] = [Table2].[ShopId]
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX([MembershipType])
            FOR [MembershipType] IN ([SilverMember], [GoldMember], [LifeMember])
    ) AS [P]
GROUP BY
    [ShopName]
```

[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a2e15/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use linq:

```
var query = from s in context.Shops
            join c in context.Customers on s.ShopNo equals c.ShopId
            group c by s.ShopName into g
            select new 
            {
              ShopName = g.Key,
              SilverMember = g.Count(c => c.MembershipType == "SilverMember"),
              GoldMember= g.Count(c => c.MembershipType == "GoldMember"),
              LifeMember= g.Count(c => c.MembershipType == "LifeMember"),
            };
```